# React: request to API trigger two times the then block, the request is sended twice

Tags: reactjs, axios

I know that the API call must be not placed into render method, but this is just for testing:
I have the below code. When i call the fetchData into the render method  the 'Send request ...' message is printed once and the respnse printed twice!?

### Output:

Page 1 ... rendering

Send request ...

{data: "Hello there", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

{data: "Hello there", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

---

Why this happens? I have checked also the network tab, and both the request is GET and not a OPTIONS related to CORS.

Also on the server the GET method handler has executed twice.

```js
import React from 'react';
const axios = require('axios').default;

class Page1 extends React.Component {

    // componentDidMount() {
    //     this.fetchData()
    // }

    fetchData() {
        console.log('Send request ...');
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/hello/')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }


    render() {
        console.log('[Page 1] render called')
        this.fetchData();
        return (<h1>Hello from Page 1. </h1>);
    }
}
export default Page1;
```

Comment: Is your app wrapped in `<React.StrictMode>`?

Comment: @KeithBrewster Yes sir, can you explain me the reason?

Comment: Sure, I just posted an answer explaining!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When your application is wrapped in `<React.StrictMode>` your components will render twice in development environments. This is for error/warning detection.  Strict mode will intentionally invoke the following class component functions twice: constructors, the `render` method, and the `shouldComponentUpdate` methods. Read more about strict mode in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects).

Comment: Okay but why 'Send request ...' is printed only onse? I am confused.

Comment: They actually intentionally hijack `console.log` during the second render. The PR with that change is here: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/18547. It was to reduce confusion with warnings being double-printed, but obviously still confusing when you see network requests firing twice

Comment: Thank you Keith! Of course and i am confused about the second request. Interesting. Thank you again! May ask you why i do not see an OPTIONS request to my backend API?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure why it wouldn't be sending an OPTIONS request, sorry